# Ask for password for IPSec VPN connection with netctl

Tags: vpn, ipsec, netctl

TL;DR: How can I connect to a VPN with IPSec without writing the password and secret in the config file, but providing it from the outside (in my case a call to my password manager `pass`)?

I already use a combination of `netctl`, `pass`, and `openconnect` to connect to a non-IPSec vpn at work. My netctl profile looks basically like this

```
razr@notebook [~]
-> % cat /etc/netctl/my-vpn 
Description='myVPN'
Interface=vpn
Connection=tuntap
Mode=tun

BindsToInterfaces=(tun0)
IP=no

PIDFILE=/run/openconnect_${Interface}.pid
SERVER=my.server.com
LOCAL_USERNAME=razr
PASS_PATH=com/myserver/razr
REMOTE_USERNAME=razr

ExecUpPost="echo '`su ${LOCAL_USERNAME} -c "DISPLAY=:0 pass ${PASS_PATH}" | head -n 1`' | /usr/bin/openconnect --background --pid-file=${PIDFILE} --interface ${Interface} --user='${REMOTE_USERNAME}' --passwd-on-stdin ${SERVER} ; chmod 644 ${PIDFILE}"                                                                  
ExecDownPre="kill -INT $(cat ${PIDFILE}) ; resolvconf -d ${Interface} ; ip link delete ${Interface}"
razr@notebook [~]
-> %
```

So when I start the profile `my-vpn`, pass is invoked to get the password at `com/myserver/razr` and therefore I am asked to unlock my pgp key (that's why there is the `DISPLAY:=0`; not ideal yet, I know :)).

Now I want to connect to a IPSec VPN. And it seems, that `openconnect` is not IPSec compatible (please correct me if I'm wrong). So I tried to use `vpnc` for it. I could already connect in my first tests with a completely filled config file. But I don't want to have my password (and maybe also not the IPSec secret) saved in the configuration file but in `pass`.

So, is it possible to provide the password and secret from the outside in a `vpnc` config? Or is there maybe another tool to do this, that I can integrate in a `netctl` profile?

Comment: If you can feed it via pipes or expect....

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure how this helps me. `vpnc` has a plaintext configuration file. No bash. And from the man page I could not find out, if (and when, how) it is possible to replace the config by command line parameters or `stdin`. So I would assume, I cannot use `vpnc` in that way, right? But is there an alternative, maybe? Maybe I can, somehow, make `openconnect` IPSec compatible? I don't think I am the first one to have this issue/requirement.